# Tab Focus changes on clicking command button

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have multiple tab and in each tab I have a form go submit data for processing, which is then displayed back in the tab. Now if I am in tab2 and submit is hit the entire page is refreshed and the focus is switched to tab1 from tab2, though the data is displayed. What needs to be done to avoid this behavior ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I basically after clicking the button I set rerender to the section nested under the tab. This made sure that there is no page reload, inturn switching the focus.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass some variable in url when you redirect and then from parameter you can decide you need to stay on first tab or second.

Otherwise don't rerender the complete part just rerender some small part.

It will solve your problem.